# Error propagation. Simpler average errors

Tags: error, error-propagation

I am designing a lab practicum to study error propagation. Let's suppose I will measure $x \pm\varepsilon_x$ and $y \pm \varepsilon_y$, where $\varepsilon_x = \varepsilon_y = \varepsilon$ for simplicity. Both variables are related to the mathematical expression:

$z=c \frac{x}{y}$, where $c$ is a constant.

I want to determine the error $\delta z$ to obtain $z \pm \delta z$, so:

$\delta z = |\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}|\varepsilon+|\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}|\varepsilon = c\varepsilon ({ \frac{1}{y}+\frac{x}{y^2}})$.

Measuring three times $x$ and $y$, I will end up with three values: $z_1 \pm \delta z_1$, $z_2 \pm \delta z_2$, and $z_3 \pm \delta z_3$. I want to obtain a mean value. Is it correct to do the following calculation?

$\bar{z} \pm \delta z = \frac{z_1 + z_2 + z_3}{3}\pm \frac{\delta z_1 +\delta z_2 +\delta z_3}{3}$

Thanks in advance.